# Question regarding a function having min and max subject to constraint that is not compact.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I know these type of question have been asked here before but I was actually confused with a hint my professor gave me regarding the following question:

> Let $D = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x + y + z = 1\}$, a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, and let $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ be a function defined as $f(x,y,z) = x^2 + 2y^2+3z^2$.
> Does $f$ have a minimum and a maximum in $D$?

Usually when the constraint is a compact set (when it's closed and bounded) we can conclude $f|_D$ does have a min and a max when $f$ is continuous. Here obviously the plane isn't bounded so we can't say that.

I did conclude $f$ has a min by taking a compact set $K$ of the plane and showing that the minimum $f$ has in $D \cap K$ is a global minimum. But how do you show that $f$ has or doesn't have a maximum? My professor hinted that $f(x) \ge \Vert x \Vert ^2$ for all $x \in R^3$. I understand $\Vert x \Vert^2 $ is unbounded, but I'm not sure how it is unbouded in $D$ and how this implies $f$ is also unbounded on $D$.

Comment: For example letting $z=0$ we have points in $D$ of the form $(x,1-x,0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x,1-x,0) \geq  ||(x,1-x,0)||$ by the hint. On the other hand, letting $x \rightarrow \infty$ we have that $||(x,1-x,0)||$ is as big as we want, that is, it is unbounded.

Comment: I see, so using the hint isn't really necessary since we can just say $f(x, 1-x, 0) = x^2+2(1-x)^2 \ge x^2 \to \infty$. Right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it directly. The importan part is choose a family of points in $D$ where the function $f$ is a big as you want. Because for example, $f(x,0,0)=x^2 \rightarrow \infty$ but the points of the form $(x,0,0)$ aren't in $D$ (except $(1,0,0)$).